# How to make Back button - to show history back only for my site

Tags: button, back

I want to make Back button in my site. 
But I want this back button to show  back page which is for my site. I mean if I've entered youtube or another site and enter my site and click back, not to return me to youtube but my previous page. If I have home page in my site and then click link from it and click back button, to return me to previous page only for my site, not previous page I've entered.
I'm using this:

```html
 <a type="button" onclick="history.back(-1);">Back</a>
```

Comment: If this isn't working, what problem(s) does it have?  If it is working, why are you here?

Comment: I want this back button to show previous page, only if this page is in my site. If previous page is not in my site, not to show it. To show previous page which is entered in my site.

Comment: You might be able to use `document.referrer` or `window.history` to determine what the "last page" was.  Then compare that value to determine if you want to send the user "back" or direct the user to a specific page.

Comment: How to compare that value from history with pages in my site. And also I want to show previous page but this previous page that is in the strusture of my site. I mean If you click Home page, then Documents and then Invoice, when click back button - to show you first Documents page, when you again click Back button, to show home page. How to do that?

Comment: Suggestion: Use [breadcrumb navigation](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/17/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices/) instead of trying to do this with a back button. You might confuse visitors by having a "Back" button that doesn't actually go to the page they were previously on.

Comment: How to do that. It doesn't have example in this link. :)